# Are there any copies of ICL MS-DOS 4.1 available for emulation?

Tags: ms-dos

The first PC I ever owned was the [ICL DRS PWS 300 as described in this press release](https://www.cbronline.com/news/icl_launches_drs_300_80286_professional_workstation_with_multi_tasking_ms_dos_41/). It was originally supplied with a copy of multitasking MS-DOS 4.1 (and Windows 1.0, which isn't mentioned in the press release). I bought it second hand and the original owner had replaced the OS with DOS 3.1 and Windows 3.0 (downgrading the DOS version because of compatibility issues), but the original disks were included. I never used them, and no longer have them.

Over time, I've wondered what using the system in its original state would have been like. I've been able to find images of Windows 1.0 to use in emulators, but have never found MS-DOS 4.1. Are there any known copies of it, or has this been lost?

Comment: (As an aside: I note from [this site](http://16bitos.com/410ms.htm) that if I'd kept those OS disks they'd now be worth nearly as much money as I paid for the whole computer...)

Comment: An aside; A friend of mine, now deceased, worked as a contractor on the firmware for the DRS PWS. Since the name is long-winded when spelt out, he nicknamed it the "Doris Pewes". ICL marketing then made a terrible mistake by issuing an edict that the machine was never, ever to be referred to by that name, naturally resulting in the whole company calling it that.

Comment: I immediately thought of WinWorld, there is a MS-DOS 4.01 here https://winworldpc.com/product/ms-dos/4x - but they seem to only have v4.00 (multitasking) - you can see the page here https://winworldpc.com/product/multitasking-ms-dos-/400 - however, at the bottom of the page there is an interesting comment that v4.10.20 can be found on BetaArchive, but you will have to sign up to investigate further.

Comment: @Geo... unfortunately the requirements for access to BetaArchive are somewhat tricky to achieve, as you need to have an "abandonware" (whatever that means) or beta title to upload that they don't already have ... and they seem to have most common titles. I mean, I don't think uploading my copy of Windows 95 is going to get me in.

Answer (score 3):

You could try getting in touch with http://www.vintage-icl-computers.com/

I was browsing through their pages earlier and see they have loads of old software disks and a DRS PWS M80 that looks to be running MS-DOS 4.1 & Windows 1.03